# How can I prevent href from firing using React onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, hyperlink

trying to make a link element (`<a>` element) with `href`. 
Why am I using `href` and not changing `history`? because I want the option to open in a new tab in browser.

The Problem is, I have a button inside the element, and when you click on it, it triggers the `href` immediately, before even getting to `stopProppagation` or `preventDefault` inside the `onClick` handler of the button. It’s like 2 different event types…

something like this:

```
...
const onButtonClick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    if (clickDisabled) return;
    if (!onClick) return;
    onClick(event);
}

return (
    <a href={someHref}>
        <button onClick={onButtonClick}>open menu</button>
    </a>
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The very first suggestion would be remove the <a> tag because you are not using the functionality of <a> tag. If your concern is about styling then use <span> tag and apply links styling to it.

Comment: Button inside a Anchor, that's not very logical.. ;)   But one solution is why not put the onClick on the Anchor, and use preventDefault on it..  And if you want to know if it's the Button that got pressed for sure, I think there is something like `targetElement` or something like that..

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma but I need the href to get the 'open in a new tab' functionality... So can't use span or div

Comment: @Keith thanks, tried to put this `onClick` on the `a` element as well. No difference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I ended up using: instead of the button `onClick` - I used `onMouseDown` which happens before the `href` trigger. 
Not the best solution, but was good enough in my case.

Answer (score -2):

```
const onButtonClick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (clickDisabled) return;
    if (!onClick) return;
    onClick(event);
}


const handleLink = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('https://URL...', '_blank');
  }

   return (
    <a href={someHref} onClick={handleLink}>
        <button onClick={onButtonClick}>open menu</button>
    </a>
)
```

Comment: Hey there :) thanks but I already tried it. when it gets to the first line of code in this function, the URL has already changed...

Comment: yep... tried it as well - putting the onClick logic on the <a> element itself. no luck...

Comment: check again :).

Comment: but then u don't need to wrap a button with the "a" tag, instead just open inside the button onClick event, but if u still want that... ur choice i guess :)

Comment: nice try, but I still want the option for a regular click to open the url in the same window (not every click should open it in a new tab, I just need to have the option)